# Python error of the "Speedtest" library : Unable to connect to the servers to test the latency

Tags: python, lib, speed-test

Python SpeedTest library Error

I have a script in python that does a speedtest and displays the result. But I don't understand why I have an error that persists.

error :

`raise SpeedtestBestServerFailure('Unable to connect to servers to ' speedtest.SpeedtestBestServerFailure: Unable to connect to servers to test latency.`

script :

```
import speedtest

st = speedtest.Speedtest()

download_speed = st.download()
print(download_speed)
```

I'm well connected, I load web pages correctly and can even do speedtest online.

Please help me

Comment: Which python & library version are you using?

Comment: Can't reproduce, please provide more details about how to reliably reproduce the problem.

Comment: I use python 3.9.2 and Speedtest-cli

Comment: This happens when I run the script. It takes a few seconds to find a server and then crashes giving me this error. I don't have any more information than that to give you. Sorry.